# How to teleop pioneer3?

Tags: control, ros, laser, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS-users,

I have some..

Hardware: Pioneer3, SICK-lms200, laptop, 2 usb-serial cables

Software: ros-hydro-desktop-full on laptop running ubuntu-12.04. sicktoolbox(works fine)

Objectives: 1. To control robot by laptop keyboard and log laser data.
2. To build map from that logged data using slam_gmapping.(I know how to achieve objective2)

I can connect my robot and sick laser using [rosaria](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C_GdAAQck-IT4H5GnsH3j6OezUbehUphtlnn8XU4XBk/edit#).

Can anyone tell me how can i move my robot using keyboard?

Thanks in advance

Hossain

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92151/how-to-teleop-pioneer3?/) by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see any sort of launch or nodes in the rosaria stack that offer keyboard teleop.

Rosaria does subscribes to the "cmd_vel" topic, so if you want you can write a simple node that listens for keyboard input and translates it into geometry_msgs/Twist messages (http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html).

I personally have been using the p2os stack for a while and it also lacks such a node. I have been getting by using the erratic robot stack and its keyboard teleop launch file. You can certainly look there to find out what needs to happen in your own version or simply use it as is.

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2013-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-23**:
Thanks. i tried with p2os. failed:) Can you be more specific what i should follow? or can u please share what you used?

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-10-23**:
I'm suggesting that you check out the keyboard teleop in the erratic stack as a model to follow.

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-23**:
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-erratic-robot
[sudo] password for albot1:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-erratic-robot
should i download and make their package in ws?

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-10-23**:
Sorry, to be more clear, I would recommend that you check out this file as an example of how to write your own keyboard teleop node:

https://github.com/arebgun/erratic_robot/blob/master/erratic_teleop/src/keyboard.cpp

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-23**:
Thanks. That link isn't active anymore. i guess https://github.com/arebgun/erratic_robot/blob/master/erratic_teleop/src/keyboard.cpp is same. so if i build this cpp file somehow and then run with $roscore and $ rosrun rosaria RosAria (to connect my robot)  i should be able to control my robot, right? or do i need anything else running?

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-10-23**:
Sorry that's frustrating. Try this: https://github.com/arebgun/erratic_robot/ Then click on "erratic_teleop", then click on "src" then "keyboard.cpp". Rosaria listens on the cmd_vel topic. You need something that translates keyboard input into a message of this type (geometry_msgs/Twist).